# How to split huge file with single line?

Tags: python, split, delimiter, large-data

I have input files with the following details:

File size: Around 3GB to 5GB 
No. of line: 1 (always) 
Delimiter: `_@%@_` 
File type: Binary 
File extension: txt  
Size of data between each delimiter: Max 5MB 
Length of data beween each delimiter: Not predictable 
Possible to have any character [`_`,`@`,`%`] in between: Yes

**Example**:

```
_@%@_4fdadfdcdfrffe3q_@%@_dfdsd8fs7dff9_@%@_jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj_@%@_fsadklfjsdfewer0_@%@_dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf_@%@_
```

Actually the file contains multiple lines separated with `_@%@_`. The problem is there's no new line character and hence I am not able to split the lines with `_@%@_`

I tried splitting the lines. But getting `MemoryError` (on line `inputF.read()`). 
I guess, if I use `for line in open(inputFilePath):`, will get `MemoryError` itself because there's only one line in the file (haven't tried).

```
inputF=open(inputFilePath, "r") 
fullFile = inputF.read()
splitted = fullFile.split("_@%@_")
```

**Output** expected (after reading it, I have to convert each lines to human readable format)

```
shirt
form
some 
human
readable
```

If I try to read it as chunks, how can I split it correctly to get exact lines?
(say, I might be getting `_@%@_4fdadfdcdf` as first chunk and `rffe3q_@%@_dfdsd8` as second chunk, right?)

**Update**:
Changed the delimiter from `###` to `_@%@_` . As I should not provide the actual data, I thought to provide just a delimiter. Didn't think about reading it character by character.

Comment: Do we know the maximum length of `###`-delimited strings?

Comment: @PM77-1 , I am sorry, I didn't get your question. You mean length of each data between each ### ? (NO, can't predict)

Comment: Using your example: `###4fdadfdcdfrffe3q###`. Question: `###_how_long_can_this_inside_substring_be###`.

Comment: Yea got it, Answer : No, we can't predict it. It is binary / hexa decimal kind of data.

Comment: Why python instead of `sed`?

Comment: Can it be more than 1GB?

Comment: I already have wrote a program in Python. Tested with small files. Which works well. But with large files, it shows MemoryError @OneCricketeer

Comment: It should be possible to read it in chunks if the actual data length between `###` delimiters is only that amount.

Comment: @PM77-1, Whole file size is more than 3GB sometimes (not always). String between ### will not be more than 5MB

Comment: Yes sounds like you are reading the entire line into memory at once. Need to iterate over the data and only process the split points. I'll see if I can post an answer shortly.

Comment: If that is all, then it can be read in chunks.

Comment: @martineau - But how can I differentiate ? (as in my last line of post)

Comment: Perhaps try [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html).

Comment: Read the file a character at a time through a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) which is basically a coroutine that will resume where it left off last time every time its `next()` method is called (until is runs out of data to read).

Comment: Can there be `#` characters in the actual data, i.e., between two delimiter triples?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode , Oh you mean single # character between actual delimiters? (may be yes)

Comment: I agree that `mmap` would probably work and might be easier to program.

Comment: @PM77-1: CSV files require rows separated with newlines.

Comment: @PM77-1 - For replacing also, I need to read the file, right?

Comment: Then what are the two data chunks in `###abc####def###`? Note there are four hashes in the middle.

Comment: And what determines what `new line` actually is?

Comment: @PM77-1: A `'\r\n'`.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode `###abc####def###` never happens. But `###abc###something#here###` may happen

Comment: @martineau - correct. EOL delimiter. BTW, in UNIX it's just `\r`. An for our task it will be `###`.  The problem is that the standard `csv` package does not allow multi-character delimiters. So we either use OS facilities to replave `###` with some byte that is not present in the file, or right our own delimiter-aware buffered reader.

Comment: @PM77-1: The [standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html) actual specifies it as CRLF.

Comment: @PM77-1 , @martineau , @don't talk just code , @OneCricketeer , @Zach Johnson
I am very sorry, Changed the delimiter from `###` to `_@%@_`  This is the actual one. As I should not provide the actual data, I thought to provide just a delimiter. Didn't think about reading it character by character.

Comment: @martineau - then we have to live with the fact that Unix/Linux world is not standard. But I'm quite OK to drop `CSV` and call it `DSV` - delimiter separated file.

Comment: @PM77-1: Indeed there really is no well-defined standard — which the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) acknowledges (and it supports other [lineterminators](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) only it doesn't really).

Comment: smilyface: Not a big deal.

Comment: @martineau First time I am doing a python program (I am a java-full-stack developer). I haven't get such support in stackoverflow yet. These much of answers in 45minutes. Unbelivable. Literally I am chatting in the stackoverflow comment box :)

Comment: smilyface: Depends on the question and time of day — but when it's good, it can be really good. ;¬)

Comment: @OneCricketeer - For you question `Why python instead of sed` - late answer : As mentioned before, already done a program in Python which works for small sized files. Another reason is it has to work in all environments (Windows / Linux / Mac)

Comment: `sed` is available in WSL2 on Windows, since it is available on (most) Linux, and definitely is on Mac

Answer (score 4):

#### Solution 1

Using [`mmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) (adapting its example code) and a regex:

```
import mmap, re

# write a simple example file
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b"_@%@_4fdadfdcdfrffe3q_@%@_dfdsd8fs7dff9_@%@_jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj_@%@_fsadklfjsdfewer0_@%@_dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf_@%@_")

with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for match in re.finditer(b'(?<=_@%@_)(.*?)(?=_@%@_)', mm):
        print(match[1])
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDbTsMwDH3vV1hFaAlU1dCQGIip@w@EpnSO1XS5kWTq9vUlzfbCA344kY/tY5/4axqc3Wx9mGdlvAsJjBG@gSCr6gGmoJIEATHXtAR5EeUlpWU1qTSA89KyepBauzZdUt1APfU1BxGBPirIQW0RYX192D/uD6@EAgmPSIFIbn4KmYmIW4pvSPRemJHwFJfGSBFpjEKPhadMnnQmkOQkw/o@XnpQU57Hc8YzXjOWYs2rf08Nz39vNQZ2xX@7AKN2MWod4w2s@c2NC2BEOg6gbP6j3GAxuwusX7Huc1c2ctY@dZx192zVZEl@W7CED8omVkS@Xr75PP8C)):

```
b'4fdadfdcdfrffe3q'
b'dfdsd8fs7dff9'
b'jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj'
b'fsadklfjsdfewer0'
b'dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf'
```

A version without hardcoding the delimiter into the pattern ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVBtS8MwEP7eX3FUpImOMpngFMf2P0RG1ruj6ZK2JhndEH97TTIR/OB9uJDn5e5Jxktoh361Ht08azsOLoC1alyAo6K4gcnpQKDAR84Q0Fnlk7WhYtKhhWGkXpQtGTPU4RzKBZTToZSgPPBLAbG4zkPEodzvbnf7R0aFjA2yY6bVRwYj4HHN/gmZnzPSMR59Enr2yJ1Xpss4R/BoIoBME7nljz1r0HD04yn2E15iz2QpiwLJaBtDONhAldHq3/ju/m9@a6Mp/UmdmuA6Pb4fhFzAUmYFYVQ4qsk3aiTxu@zK8uDAqtC0oPukYt1jYgVXYvu6@ST8kqK@20qxvV6qmvpmQEobrJXXFKlGp/sg8qy3h3c5z98)):

```
delimiter = '_@%@_'
with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    ed = re.escape(delimiter)
    for match in re.finditer(f'(?<={ed})(.*?)(?={ed})'.encode(), mm):
        print(match[1])
```

#### Solution 2

Or with `mmap` alone:

```
import mmap

# write a simple example file
with open("hello.txt", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b"_@%@_4fdadfdcdfrffe3q_@%@_dfdsd8fs7dff9_@%@_jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj_@%@_fsadklfjsdfewer0_@%@_dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf_@%@_")

delimiter = b'_@%@_'
with open("hello.txt", "r+b") as f:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    start = mm.find(delimiter) + len(delimiter)
    while (stop := mm.find(delimiter, start)) != -1:
        print(mm[start:stop])
        start = stop + len(delimiter)
```

Output:

```
b'4fdadfdcdfrffe3q'
b'dfdsd8fs7dff9'
b'jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj'
b'fsadklfjsdfewer0'
b'dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf'
```

#### Note

In all cases, if you want `str` instead of `bytes`, apply `.decode()` to the results.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and update you here.

Comment: Nice answer. Glad you were able to type all those special characters in despite your hand injury.

Comment: @martineau Not injured, was just eating and hand was too dirty for keyboard.

Comment: Oh…must be recalling what you said wrong (or misunderstood it). Anyhow, besides the `mmap` idea, I'm impressed with the fairly advanced regex you came up with to split the data up with in conjunction with `re.finditer()`.

Comment: @martineau Meh, just naive lookarounds. Maybe I could also make `(.*?)_@%@_` work and it might be faster, but I'd have to handle the very first delimiter, so the lookarounds seemed easier. Btw I had used mmap like twice before, so I wasn't fully unfamiliar with it, but it was a while back and I vaguely remember there being annoying differences between Windows/Linux. And then there's that it does bytes, not strings. Though the delimiter chars are all ASCII, so they work even in UTF-8 data, just possibly need that `decode()` you mentioned if they do want strings.

Comment: @smilyface Also try the second solution I just added, should be faster.

Comment: I suggest you use `re.escape()` and not hard-code the delimiter string.

Comment: @martineau Alright, added that as well. But by now I like my non-regex `find` solution best anyway. Should've thought of that earlier. By now I really think the lookaround-finditer solution was the *easy* way out, not advanced and not something to be impressed with :-)

Comment: Totally agree that not using `re` is the better way. Besides being way simpler, it's likely faster — folks often don't appreciate how slow using a regex can be.

Comment: @martineau Yes, I did some testing on 50 MB, my regex solution took ~1.2 seconds, my `find` solution ~0.3 seconds, and Alain's ~0.1 seconds (already upvoted that one).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode - Sure, I will try second solution. First solution works for normal files (not yet tested with large files - due to some other technical issues). Will update once tested all

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of how you can do it with chunks:

```
chunkSize = 10000 # Whatever number you want
lastLine  = "" 
lines     = []
with open(inputfilePath,"r") as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(chunkSize)
        if not chunk: break
        *parts,lastLine = (lastLine+chunk).split("_@%@_")
        lines.extend(parts)
    if lastLine: 
       lines.append(lastLine) # in case file doesn't end with "_@%@_"

print(lines)

['', '4fdadfdcdfrffe3q', 'dfdsd8fs7dff9', 'jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj', 'fsadklfjsdfewer0', 'dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf']
```

You could also make this into an iterator function that will allow you to process the lines as you go without storing everything in memory:

```
def iReadlines(file,chunkSize=4096,eol="\n"):
    lastLine = ""
    while True:
        chunk = file.read(chunkSize)
        if not chunk : break
        *lines,lastLine = (lastLine+chunk).split(eol)
        yield from lines
    if lastLine: yield lastLine
        
with open(inputfilePath,"r") as f:
    for line in iReadlines(f,100000,"_@%@_"):
        print(line) # or do what you need with each line


4fdadfdcdfrffe3q
dfdsd8fs7dff9
jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj
fsadklfjsdfewer0
dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf
```

Answer (score 2):

`.read(size)` takes a number of bytes / characters to read, so you can write a generator function to read each character until the last `N` characters you read equal your separator (where `N = len(separator)`), and then yield the chunk.

```
def chunked_read(input_file, separator):
    collector = []
    N = len(separator)
    separator_list = [c for c in separator]
    while True:
        char = input_file.read(1) # Read one character
        if not char: # Nothing more to read
            if collector: # If collector isn't empty, yield it before breaking
                yield ''.join(collector)
            break # Nothing more to do

        collector.append(char) # Add to collector

        if collector[-N:] == separator_list: # If the last N chars were your separator, 
            # yield the first through last-but-N slice of collector
            yield ''.join(collector[:-N])
            collector = [] # And then reset collector
```

To test it,

```
import io

s = io.StringIO("_@%@_4fdadfdcdfrffe3q_@%@_dfdsd8fs7dff9_@%@_jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj_@%@_fsadklfjsdfewer0_@%@_dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf_@%@_")

for item in chunked_read(s, "_@%@_"):
    print(repr(item))
```

Gives:

```
''
'4fdadfdcdfrffe3q'
'dfdsd8fs7dff9'
'jfdksadfdsfsdfjsalj'
'fsadklfjsdfewer0'
'dfsdfjsdlfdffdufdfudyfdf'
```

Comment: In the spirit of not dealing with the entire data set at once, consider not turning your example result into a list: `for chunk in chunked_read(s): print(s)`

Comment: @Pranav, First of all thank you and sorry to ask you this. If the delimiter is `#$#` what would be the change?

Comment: @Woodford true. I wanted to show that there's an empty item at the start, but I also added the loop to print each item

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi: I think it would be worth mentioning that you're using a generator function.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Your OS is smart enough to cache disk reads. You aren't hitting the disk for each character and no matter what method you're using you must examine every character in the input.

Comment: nit: `if char == ""` same as `if not char:` and `''.join(collector_list)` would be more optimal than concatenating onto a string

Comment: @smilyface instead of incrementing a counter and checking if it's equal to 3, you could check if the last three characters of `collector` are `#$#`

Comment: @Woodford Didn't mean disk reading, meant all that Python code. But seems 5 MB take ~1 second, so ~15 minutes total. Reasonable.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and update you here.