# Mmap throws an error: mmap object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, mmap

I am writing a code that should search faster in a large file using mmap.

```
import re
import mmap

with open('words.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f1, open('source.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f2, open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as output_file:

    # Map the contents of file1 and file2 into memory
    file1_contents = mmap.mmap(f1.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    file2_contents = mmap.mmap(f2.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)

    # Create a regular expression pattern to match the words in file2
    pattern = re.compile(b'(' + b'|'.join(file2_contents.split()) + b')')

    # Search for the regular expression pattern in the mapped file1 contents
    for line in iter(file1_contents.readline, b""):
        if pattern.search(line):
            # Write the line to the output file
            output_file.write(line.decode())`
```

When I try to run the code, it throws an error: `AttributeError: 'mmap.mmap' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: So `file2_contents` is a `mmap` object and it doesn't have a `split` attribute. What is your question?

Comment: [How to split huge file with single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69037040/6045800)

Comment: I got it, but don't know what to do next!

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you for the link but I don't know how to adapt it to my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mmap object does not have a `split()` method like a regular string object. You need to convert the `mmap` object to a regular string object before you can use the `split()` method. To do this, you can call the `decode()` method on the `mmap` object to convert it to a string, like this:

```py
pattern = re.compile(b'(' + b'|'.join(file2_contents.decode().split()) + b')')
```

Comment: 'mmap.mmap' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Try this: `file_contents = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), 0,access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
file_string = file_contents.read().decode()
`

Comment: Thank you, it works. Another issue, it throws a Memory Error, the file has approx. 12GB, i have 16GB RAM.